# Run Java to Kotlin converter from the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

You can use the Kotlin plug-ins for Intellij and Eclipse to convert Java files to Kotlin. Can this conversion be done from the command line some how without either of these IDEs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that it's possible, but there's no tool for that, just code. There are tests in [j2k module](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/idea/231.8770.17/plugins/kotlin/j2k) in Kotlin Github repository, the example below is taken from the [tests (AbstractJavaToKotlinConverterSingleFileTest)](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/idea/231.8770.17/plugins/kotlin/j2k/new/tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/nj2k/AbstractNewJavaToKotlinConverterSingleFileTest.kt):

```
private fun fileToKotlin(text: String, settings: ConverterSettings, project: Project): String {
    val file = createJavaFile(text)
    val converter = JavaToKotlinConverter(project, settings,
                                          IdeaReferenceSearcher, IdeaResolverForConverter)
    return converter.filesToKotlin(listOf(file), J2kPostProcessor(formatCode = true)).results.single()
}
```

I suppose, you can make a .jar of that module and write your own simple wrapper for `JavaToKotlinConverter` to make it work on files.

---

UPD: the code has migrated to the `intellij-community` repository, you can find relevant tests here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/2382372993bee233bc6fce95c3917a68a33da111/plugins/kotlin/j2k/new/tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/nj2k/AbstractNewJavaToKotlinConverterSingleFileTest.kt

Comment: Thanks for answer and the the pointer to the code, @hotkey. Much appreciated.

Comment: @TravisSpencer, you're welcome. If the answer satisfied you could you please accept it to move question to the answered?

Comment: @hotkey the links in your answer are broken. Do you know if something like that exists anywhere?